# Resolve netbios name to ip address without editing hostfile

Tags: powershell, hosts

I'm working on a powershell script which requires a domain controller to be accessed via its netbios name, NP-DOMAIN.

However, the domain controller exists at the other end of a VPN tunnel, and there are no WINS servers configured nor DNS search suffix.

I have no administrator rights, so can't edit the local hosts file.

I have the IP address of the domain controller, but I need to specify the netbios name. Is there a way I can add name resolution of the netbios name to the IP address, just for this PowerShell session?

The part of the script that requires the netbios name is:

```
$DomainEntry = New-Object -TypeName System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry "LDAP://$($netBiosName)" ,$credentials.UserName,$($credentials.GetNetworkCredential().password)
```

The purpose of the script is to allow users to change their passwords on the remote domain controller.

Comment: Nothing immediately comes to mind. What API requires you to specify the netbios name? If you show us your script there might be alternatives

Comment: Based on your good advice, I've updated the question.

Comment: What errors do you get when trying to contact it on IP alone, ie `"LDAP://1.2.3.4/DC=NP,DC=DOMAIN,DC=TLD"` instead of `LDAP://$netBiosName/`

Comment: I get: 
format-default : The following exception occurred while retrieving member "distinguishedName": "The server is not operational.